# unable to see recent commits on remote git repo

Tags: git, github

I have a local repo with branch X, which is associated with a private GitHub repo branch X. There are two "remotes" added, origin and backup, both pointing to the same GitHub repo (using https).

If I do a **git log origin/X** I see the most recent commit is 826d562 from May 2nd. If I do the same with **backup/X**, I see dc32de2, d78498c, f3ed5a8, 16f7c17, and then 826d562, with the others from 5/15 to 5/6.

IOW, it shows more recent commits that I and others have pushed to the remote repo.

I created a VM on another machine, setup the same remote repo, did a fetch and checked out branch X and it too, shows 826d562 as the HEAD. A coworker on his machine, sees the dc32de2 version and all the others.

If I go to GitHub and look at this branch on the repo, it shows the latest as 826d562 and **not** dc32de2!

Why do I see (or not see) these newer commits on the remote between the various machines?

Why do two "remotes" pointing to the same repo, from the same machine, show different things?

I'm totally baffled!

Comment: Please clarify the order of the commits. What's the output of `git log --oneline origin/x` and `git log --oneline backup/x`?

Comment: Do a `git fetch origin` first?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "checked out branch X"? You should try to setup a tracking branch that will track your remote branch `X`.

Comment: @Cupcake, origin has 826d562 (HEAD 5/2) and then older commits. backup shows dc32de2 (HEAD 5/16), d78498c, f3ed5a8, 16f7c17 (5/6), and then 826d562 (5/2). So backup is showing 4 newer commits. A coworker sees the same as what I see with backup.

Comment: @gravetii This is part of DevStack (devstack.org) open-source software, where they have a script that clones the repo for a specific branch. Originally, I've done that and it was assigned to origin. Later, I created backup (git remote add backup https:/github.com/...), which points to the same repo. Doing "git remote show origin" indicates that branch X is tracked. Same for backup remote.

Comment: @Sam I haven't touched this system, as it is the only one that "works" (I can see the newer commits). On another machine (a VM on a laptop), I can only see the 5/2 commit as the head. I've done "git fetch origin", "git checkout X", but still it does not show. A "git log origin/X" doesn't show the newer 5 commits either. I've found that one other coworker sees the same issue I do. Someone mentioned something about keys expiring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along the lines of authentication expiring, I did some Googling and came across this command:

```
git credential-cache exit
```

I did that, and then did a fetch, and got an update. I did "git status" and it says my branch is behind, so I rebased and now when I do "git log" I see all the recent commits.

I'm using https to access the Github repo, using Ubuntu 12.04 as my OS in all cases. If anyone has thoughts on the reasoning behind what is going on, I'd love to hear it, but it does work now on the other system.